# Assigning Tasks on Bonita Soft

Tags: task, bonita

i am using Bonita Studio Community 7.8.3
now the challenge is i am trying to create a Process and assign different tasks to differnt approving authorities and i wouldnt be using the william.bates and the helen.kelly on the organisation as created inside the studio.

Now i Followed what was here https://community.bonitasoft.com/questions-and-answers/bonitasoft-626-how-assign-specific-user-next-task but when i try to do some assignments apparently somethings appear to be missing in this case. Asides the one for get started (Which i have been able to handle easily) I have not been able to see a way to get the tasks to the other users.

I want the approving authorities to have the names of the following

- Supervisor
- IC&A
- GH Operations
- DH Operations
- Payment officer

  And the whole Process ends, I have been able to do something like this with K2 now i wan to have it done with Bonita BPM and i have this issues
  Now i want to know how i can assign tasks to this different people from the originator and also call API for payment and others

How can this be done.
Very new to using Bonita BPM.

Comment: did you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

- declare several actors in your process definition (one per name you listed)
- mapped each actor to a task or to a lane that includes one or several task (select the task and go in General -> Actors tab)
- configure the process (using the wrench icon) to map your actor to users or groups of users

I recently wrote a [blog post](https://community.bonitasoft.com/blog/assign-task-user) about actors and actor filters in Bonita that might be helpful.

You might also want to take a look at the following [video](https://youtu.be/DhkqvTaMxao) that is part of Bonita Camp videos series (a tutorial with exercises for Bonita beginners).